# Is it possible to get data from redirection page in AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm in trouble. I'm trying to do something which can appear easy but I don't manage to do it.

Here is the situation :

I have **3 different html pages** :

- The **first one** called index.html is my main page with a button to lauch a test in AJAX (I'm gonna talk about it after).
- The **second one** corresponds to a redirection to the third page.
- The **third one** has data.

What I wanna do is :

**Click on "test" button on the first page and then start an AJAX request on the second one to reach data from the third one** (with the redirection) **to print it in the first.**

I mean the first page calls the second one in AJAX, but the just to redirect on a specific third page. Depending on the third page which is called, data returned to the first page will change.

Do you think it's possible to find a solution to this problem in Javascript ? I hope I have been clear enough.

Thank you in advance for answer.

Comment: _"I hope I have been clear enough."_ - not really. What does for example _"It generates an url which will be test"_ mean exactly? Could you describe it sounding less biblical, and more technical?

Comment: Why not directly get the data from the third page?

Comment: I've edited my post according to your comments. Tell me if it remains unclear.

Comment: How is the second page redirecting to the third one?

Comment: With a 'Location.href="thirdpage.html"'

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing doesn't really make sense. There are methods of redirection that AJAX follows (an HTTP 301 code, for example). However, what you are describing is not that sort of redirect. You are describing Javascript code that, when run, will redirect the browser elsewhere.

However, you are not loading that Javascript with the browser, you are downloading the page via AJAX. Once it is downloaded, you will have the text that represents that page, but in order to find out where it would redirect to when run, you would either have to run it and somehow capture the redirect value (not recommended), or parse it yourself (also not recommended).

There are other options that could work, depending on what you are trying to accomplish:

- The server could return an HTTP redirect code when the second page is requested
- The second page could instead be a text or JSON file containing a URL, which the first page could read, then request data from that URL.
- If there is logic in the second page that determines where the redirect goes, it could be moved to the first page
- You could have the second page employ server-side scripting (PHP, etc) to determine what data should be returned and return it directly to the first page

Comment: Thank you for the time u took to write that. I think I understand how I was wrong.